# Salesforce1 - Quick Questions

Tags: salesforce1-app

a) What other technologies (apart from Apex/VF) are needed to build apps on salesforce 1 ?.

b) Am I right in assuming that my mobile app's UI elements will be based on the mobile app development of my choice (android/ios etc)  but the logic (apex/configuration logic) will be run by the Salesforce servers ?

PS : I know that I need to ask questions which can answered specifically.
     I hope these are conforming to the rules.

Answer (score 2):

For SF1 you'll be working with Delcarative Salesforce, Visualforce (certain elements of it at least) and Apex for any custom controllers / remoting methods.

For the large part the UI is straight-up HTML 5 and you'll probably want to use a Javascript framework of choice to help you manage the UI and make it nice and fast. Visualforce pages that use Javascript & Apex remoting tend to be nice and quick, VF that calls back to an Apex controller for everything (transferring the view state) is a lot slower by nature and not so well suited to mobile. Everything is online only at the moment, and for future reference Apex can only be run on Salesforce, there is no way of running it anywhere else at present (and I'd be surprised if that option ever became available).

SF1 development does not require any native iOS/Android code.

Answer (score 0):

In short, most of salesforce1 specific development is configuration based. You can add visualforce pages through tabs if these visualforce pages are checked as mobile. It is your own responsibility that these visualforce pages are responsive.

Within visualforce pages, you can use all front end technologies you could usually use within visualforce (js frameworks). Most standard visualforce elements are not responsive, so that's definitely something to keep in mind.